# Java EE project folder structure in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms

I am new to Java EE programming. I am attempting to write a JMS sender in Eclipse using Java EE. I have created a new Java EE project and now my doubt is what is the folder structure and where to write my JMS sender java file.

I am using JBoss AS. My requirement is that I have to push the messages to a JMS Queue using this JMS sender application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to write a MDB ( Message driven bean) to consume your JMS messages. For clarity purposes i will present a small example;

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue =   "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/offlinemsg"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class MessageHandlerMDB implements MessageListener {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessageHandlerMDB.class);


@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    log.info("Message received in MessageHandlerMDB");


}

}
```

On deployment of your app the server will identify the message driven bean based on the annotations and create a queue for you. You can then send message to this queue as usual through a ConnectionFactory. If you are sending a message through the same application within Jboss then you can write as follows;

```
 private void sendObjectToQueue(Serializable object) {


    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer sender = null;
    Connection connect = null;

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Entered sendObjectToQueue(" + object.getClass());
    }

    try {

        Context context = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context
                .lookup("ConnectionFactory");

        Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("queue/offlinemsg");
        connect = factory.createConnection();
        session = connect.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        sender = session.createProducer(queue);

        ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();

        message.setObject(object);
        sender.send(message);
        sender.close();
        connect.close();

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("The " + object.getClass() + " object was sent to jms queue");
        }

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Sending object to queue failed", e);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Sending object to queue failed", e);


    } finally {

        if (sender != null) {
            try {
                sender.close();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Closed jms session");
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error("Closing jms session failed", e);
            }
        }

        if (connect != null) {
            try {
                connect.close();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Closed jms session");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Closing jms session failed", e);
            }
        }

        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Closed jms session");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Closing jms session failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need further clarification. Hope this helps.

***Edited****

If you are calling from a normal java class then following code is required(note that this is specific to JBoss)

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
Queue queue = (Queue)ic.lookup("/queues/MyQueue");
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
connection.start();
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Test");
producer.send(message);
```

Note that you should reuse the Connection creation and session creation as best practices...

Comment: @ Dinu : Thank you so much for clarifying my doubt . After creating EJB project I got two Projects . One is EJB and other is EJB Clinet .Can I write this code in EJB clinet project?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, i have edited my post to show how to call from a normal java client. You can include the last portion of code in your EJB client project and the first code snippet part in the EJB project to be deployed on the server.